# Action name mistaken as show id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still new to Rails, and so I have this issue.

I have a controller name Client. In the routing I have:

```
resources :clients do
   get 'confirmation_import/:page', action: :confirmation_import, on: :collection, :defaults => {:page => 1}
   collection do
     get :autocomplete
     post :confirmation_import
     post :import
   end
end
```

As you can see, I'm using pagination. When I go back to the first page though, the page param is not used, so the link becomes `/clients/confirmation_import`. From there I'm getting an error because a `before_action` for `show` action is being used, and it says my `id` param is `confirmation_import`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally routes are matched from top to bottom and as the route for `show` action is defined before the route for `confirmation_report` action it is routing to `show` action with `confirmation_report` as `id`.

So, put your route for `confirmation_report` before `show` route as below:

```
get 'clients/confirmation_import/:page' => 'clients#confirmation_import, :defaults => {:page => 1}

resources :clients do
  collection do
    get :autocomplete
    post :confirmation_import
    post :import
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it still doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Can you post your routes generated by `rake routes`?

Comment: As the `page` param is part of the route and not a query param rails will obviously routes to `show` action If there is no `page` param.